# Electron JS stream from getUserMedia() not keeping 1080p resolution

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to share screen using ElectronJS and WebRTC. Unfortunately, I'm having some inconsistencies with resolution.

I have a globalStream, which is set using the following code:

```
      globalStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          audio: {
              mandatory: {
                  chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                  chromeMediaSourceId: selectedMedia
              }
          },
          video: {
              mandatory: {
                  chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                  chromeMediaSourceId: selectedMedia,
                  minWidth: 1920,
                  maxWidth: 1920,
                  minHeight: 1080,
                  maxHeight: 1080
              }
          }
      })
```

The variable "selectedMedia" is a string with the id of the screen I want to stream, which is "screen:0:0" in this case. The resolution of this screen is 1080p.

If I use the following code to check the height of this stream, right after it's created, I get the response of 1080, and sometimes 720.

```
console.log(globalStream.getVideoTracks()[0].getSettings().height);
```

I also have a function just to check this variable in the console, at runtime:

```
function checkStream() {
  console.log(globalStream.getVideoTracks()[0].getSettings().width);
  console.log(globalStream.getVideoTracks()[0].getSettings().height);
}
```

The result of this function is **always** 1280 for width and 720 for height.

My guess is that right after selecting this media source and associating it to a variable, it has the right resolution (1080p), but after some time, it goes down to 720p.

And my question is: Why is it happening?

I said I'm using WebRTC just to give some context, but at this stage I didn't even reach the part where the stream via WebRTC happens. I noticed the lower resolution on my preview, before starting the WebRTC connection. It is clearly not 1080p.

I coudn't find anything about it in the internet, and in the Electron documentation.

Am I missing something or this should be working?